# Is it possible to detect idle time even across tabs?

Tags: javascript, detect, python-idle

I have a script that sends a time-sensitive notification to users when there is a new question directed to them. However, I found that some people leave their computers open and go grab lunch, therefore missing notifications.

I'm looking to put together a script that detects if the user is idle for 5 minutes, and if so, it would show them as 'offline' and close down notifications.

I was curious if it is possible to detect inactivity even across tabs? (for example if a user switches to another tab to Facebook.com and stays active there, they would be seen as 'active' even though they are not on our webpage specifically).

Comment: This is completely possible with `localStorage` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993567/javascript-session-timeout-with-popup-alert-for-multiple-tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that happens when the user is NOT on your side is impossible to track (luckily).

So not this is not possible (think about the security).

**UPDATE**

Now that I think of it. It *is* possible, however very unlikely that you can do it. If your name would have been Google you would have come a long way, because lots of websites use Google analytics. But other than that: NO not possible for reasons mentioned.

Comment: haha, right. That makes sense. I'll think of alternative hacks and see what else we can do to generate the same effect. Maybe notify the user to confirm that they are active every half an hour of on-page inactivity, with a 'snooze' function

Answer (score 1):

Store their last activity in a database table when they are active.  You can use mouse movement, keypresses, or some other activity to update the timestamp.  Periodically poll that table with an ajax call on the page on which the user would see their online/offline status.  If the last active time is > 5 minutes, show them as offline or idle.

Comment: How about across different tabs though? If a user goes and be active on Facebook after opening our website, is it possible to detect if they are active?

Comment: No.  There are security issues in trying to do that.  You would not want it to be possible that another tab was snooping on your banking activity.  You can only tell if they are active on your site.  They would not be active should they be on Facebook.

Comment: I was solving this same problem and was thinking of the same solution .. but i am worried on the performance bottleneck as localStorage/IndexeDb both are disk operations so if the website is used heavily these mousemove events surely will have impact as there will be continuous disk operations on mouse move which is very common in websites.. I could not think of any other solution till this point.. Do u have something in mind for that?

Answer (score 1):

if I am on such a thing I use either the HTML5 Visibility API or fallback to blur and focus events observing when the user left the page and then returns... leaving means unfocus the browser window or tab (but still keeping the page open)

but since you wanna react on inactivity... hmmm you could start a timeout (of course that would need a global event delegation for many events to stop it if something happens like submit, click, change, mousemove and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Code is:

```
var inactivityTime = function () {
    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function logout() {
        alert("You are now logged out.")
        //location.href = 'logout.php'
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout, 3000)
        // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to elaborate on how your code helps to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement this functionality on my clients website. Didnt find any idleal solution for this in web.Finally I had to twig my code,think of some logic and implement this.The code goes as below--

```
     `/*Put this code inside script tag whereever you want to execute the inactivity popup*/
     var t;
    //set the timeout period  
    var timeoutPeriod = '${inactiveIntervalMillis}';  
    //detect various events  
    callUserEvents();  
     `

//remove the logged Out storage after popup is closed by user  
function removeLocalStorage() {  
localStorage.removeItem("loggedOut");  
}      
//call this function whenever we detect user activity  
function resetUserActivity() {  
resetTimer();  
}  
//If the user is logged out and it clicks on other tabs,the popup will be               displayed there too  
function checkIfUserLoggedOut() {  
    if (localStorage.getItem("loggedOut")) {  
        loadLoginModal("/includes/gadgets/popup-content.jsp", 400, 230,  
            undefined);  
    }  
}  

// Call this method when any window onloads,this helps to check if multiple         tabs are opened by same site  
function incrementCounter() {   
    checkIfUserLoggedOut();  
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter") == "NaN") {  
        localStorage.setItem("counter", "0");  
    } else {  
        var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter")) + 1;  
        localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);  
    }  
    resetTimer();  
}  
//after time interval,this method will be called  
function handleIdleTimedOut() {  
//get the current localStorage Object  
    window.sharedCounter = localStorage.getItem("counter");  
//If no tabs are opened,then popup will be shown here.  
    if (window.localCounter == window.sharedCounter) {  
        loadLoginModal("/includes/gadgets/popup-content.jsp", 400,               230,undefined);  
        localStorage.setItem("loggedOut", "true");  
    }   
}  

function resetTimer() {  
//save counterin current Window object,and after timeout period you can     match   it,if by chance multiple tabs were opened,the counter will be     different,popup  wont be shown in current window at incorrect time.  
    window.localCounter = localStorage.getItem("counter");  
    clearTimeout(t);  
    t = setTimeout(handleIdleTimedOut, timeoutPeriod);  
}  
function callUserEvents(){  
window.onload=incrementCounter  
window.onscroll = resetUserActivity;  
window.onmousemove = resetUserActivity;    
window.ondblclick = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncontextmenu = resetUserActivity;  
window.onclick = resetUserActivity;  
window.onkeypress = resetUserActivity;  
window.onpageshow = resetUserActivity;  
window.onresize = resetUserActivity;  
window.onfocus = incrementCounter;  
window.ondrag = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncopy = resetUserActivity;  
window.oncut = resetUserActivity;  
window.onpaste = resetUserActivity;     
}  

`
```