# Countdown in setInterval function with sweet Alert plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am trying to implement countdown to [sweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). After 20 minutes of inactivity sweet alert pops up and displays that the session is about to time out and user has two options: to log out or continue, which restarts the idle timer. The idle timer is reset also when the mouse is moved or a click is made. My problem is that I would like to display a countdown in the [sweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) title's span (`title: "Teie sessioon on aegumas <span id='secondsLeft'></span> sekundi pärast!",`  )from 60-0 (seconds) before it logs out automatically. 
I tried all the ways, but nothing worked. The countdown showed up, but didn't restart.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            var idleTime = 0;
            //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement

            function timerIncrement() {
                idleTime ++;
                if (idleTime >= 5) { // For testing 5 seconds else 20 minutes
                        swal({   
                        html: true,
                        title: "Teie sessioon on aegumas <span id='secondsLeft'></span> sekundi pärast!",  
                        text: "Sessiooni pikendamiseks vajutage nuppu Jätka, välja logimiseks vajutage Välju." ,   
                        type: "warning",   
                        showCancelButton: true,   
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
                        confirmButtonText: "Jätka",   
                        cancelButtonText: "Välju",  
                        timer: 60000, //3600
                        closeOnConfirm: false,   
                        closeOnCancel: false }, function(isConfirm){
                        if (isConfirm) {    
                            swal("Jätkatud!", 
                                 "Teie sessiooni pikendati 1 tunni võrra.", 
                                 "success");  

                        } else {     
                            swal("Väljutud", 
                                 "Teid suunatakse tagasi sisselogimis lehele", 
                                 "error"),
                                location.href = "logout.php?logout=true";
                        } 
                    });
                }
            }
            //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
            var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 minute

            $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                idleTime = 0;
            });
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                idleTime = 0;
            }
```

Comment: did you find the answer already?

Comment: @khakiout no sir. still trying to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, what's happening to your code right now is that the `sweetAlert` plugin is being recreated every second. If that's what you intend to happen, you can use this.

This snippet makes use of a `countDown` variable to be displayed with the `title` attribute of the `sweetAlert` plugin. Each time `timerIncrement()` is called, the `sweetAlert` plugin is recreated and the `countDown` is decremented.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var idleTime = 0;
  var countDown = 20; //assuming countdown is 20 seconds

  function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime++;
    if (idleTime >= 5) { // For testing 5 seconds else 20 minutes
      swal({
        html: true,
        title: "Teie sessioon on aegumas " + countDown + " pärast!",
        ... // other configs
      });
      countDown--;
    }
  }
  //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
  var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 minute

  $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
    idleTime = 0;
    resetCountdown(); //reset
  });
  $(this).keypress(function(e) {
    idleTime = 0;
    resetCountdown(); //reset
  });

  function resetCountdown() {
    countDown = 20;
  }
});
```

Comment: It works indeed! And I understand the solution as well. Excellent explanation. One more question. How can I apply this to all the pages?

Comment: @raqulka you just need to include the script in all pages. it should work fine.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. I am using cookies so when user logs out from one page, it logs out from all the pages/ tabs opened. When user opens another tab from my application, then timeout would considers that page as well: i hope you understand what I am trying to say :d

Comment: @raqulka you can use `localStorage` for that. take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993567/javascript-session-timeout-with-popup-alert-for-multiple-tabs where the `idleTime` value is stored in the `localStorage`

Comment: Thank you sir! You saved my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var closeInSeconds = 5,
        displayText = "I will close in #1 seconds.",
        timer;

    swal({
        title: "Auto close alert!",
        html: "<p class='Alert'>Hello</p>",
        timer: closeInSeconds * 1000,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });

    timer = setInterval(function() {

        closeInSeconds--;

        if (closeInSeconds < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
        }

        $('.Alert').html(displayText.replace(/#1/, closeInSeconds));

    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: copy past on html page, but must reference javascript and sweetalert css and js file first.