# Sweet alert. Display countdown in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have an issue with displaying the countdown in sweetalert message. After click i use the "A message with auto close timer". I want that countdown to be in the message and user can see the countdown.

```
swal({  
    title: "Please w8 !",
    text: "Data loading...",
    timer: 10000,
    showConfirmButton: false 
});
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible without changing the library. Perhaps [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718899/countdown-in-setinterval-function-with-sweet-alert-plugin) can work for you.

Comment: See my answer. You will find complete solution (:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is impossible to do with SweetAlert. It doesn't support counting on UI. But never say never :-)

I have prepared a little hack, which can help you to do that. Just add the code below to your application, and you will see live counting mechanism. And don't forget to add jQuery too.

```
var
    closeInSeconds = 5,
    displayText = "I will close in #1 seconds.",
    timer;

swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",   
    text: displayText.replace(/#1/, closeInSeconds),   
    timer: closeInSeconds * 1000,   
    showConfirmButton: false 
});

timer = setInterval(function() {

    closeInSeconds--;

    if (closeInSeconds < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    $('.sweet-alert > p').text(displayText.replace(/#1/, closeInSeconds));

}, 1000);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: WOW hack goes very well. Thank you a lot ! It is doing exactly what i wanted...:)

Comment: This is amazing. Easy solution, but really clever. Wouldn't come up with it myself but is easy to customize and understand. +1!

Answer (score 6):

Here is better solution

```
var timer = 10, // timer in seconds
    isTimerStarted = false;

(function customSwal() {
    swal({  
        title: "Please w8 !",
        text: "Data loading..." + timer,
        timer: !isTimerStarted ? timer * 1000 : undefined,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });
    isTimerStarted = true;
    if(timer) {
        timer--;
        setTimeout(customSwal, 1000);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why you seting to timer property "undefined" if isTimerStarted == true?